# How can I return image address to Django template from a function of the file views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I need to display an image using **Django templates** but don't know how the "image address" will be returned from the function of the file **views.py**

The image address will be stored according to the "**id**" of the project (a project has an image associated with it).

Here is the function of the **views.py** file that I am writing:-

```
def file_path(request, awp_id):
    Component_Progress_Update_inst = get_object_or_404( Component_Progress_Update, pk=awp_id)
    filepath = Component_Progress_Update_inst.Supporting_documents.name
    filepath = "/media/"+filepath
    print(filepath)
    # Returning the file path
    return HttpResponse(filepath)
```

Following is the **image tag**, I am writing in HTML file:-

```
<img src="{% url 'component_progress:file_path' awp.id %}" alt="Supporting image" width="200" height="200">
```

But the image is not getting displayed, instead of the image this "alt text" is getting printed.

While I have tried displaying the image directly -> By directly writing that address in image "**src**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have to make changes in return line, it should be as follows:-

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(filepath)
```

It worked fine after using it !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:
src="{{object.image.url}}"

With image.url you get the path of the image.